# Фибоначчиева куча - одинаковые ключи

Tags: алгоритм, структуры-данных

Не могу разобраться как избавиться от дублирования ключей при реализации фибоначчиевой пирамиды. Дело в том, что ключ может быть глубоко, а добавляем мы новый элемент сразу в корень, уплотняем лишь потом, как же тогда избавится от дублирования?

Answer (score 1):

Часто при реализации структуры данных можно избавиться от дублирующих ключей следущим трюком: давайте вообще не хранить в структуре дублирующие ключи, а просто к каждом ключу будем дополнительно хранить, сколько таких ключей "лежит" в структуре.

Тогда операции добавления/удаления чуть поменяются:
1. При добавлении нужно сначала попробовать найти нужный ключ в структуре. Если нашёлся - то просто увеличиваем ему счётчик. Не нашёлся - добавляем новый ключ в структуру, ставим счётчик в единицу.
2. При удалении мы находим имеющийся ключ в структуре, уменьшаем счётчик, а сам ключ из структуры удаляем только если счётчик упал до нуля.

Если требуется хранить какие-то дополнительные данные вместе с ключами, счётчик можно заменить на связный список этих самых дополнительных данных.